# dynamically handle SubMenu Items in android

Tags: android, menu

As I am creating sub menu items dynamically , so its obvious that the MenuItems's index will be dynamic only. so here what i facing the problem.

so far i have successfully create the menu items dynamically inside ***onCreateOptionsMenu*** function

```
SubMenu switchMenu = menu.addSubMenu("My Menu");

for(int i=0;i<myList.getListSize();i++){
 switchMenu.add(FILE, NEW_MENU_ITEM+i, 0, myList.get(i).data);  
}
```

Now the problem comes when Menu Items are selected inside ***onOptionsItemSelected***

```
//get the the selected index 
int selectedMenuIndex = item.getItemId();    

// Pass it to a function in another activity 
myList.myActivity.switch(selectedMenuIndex);

//Finishing the current activity and loads the previously selected
finish();
```

Whenever the parent menu loads and i click on it to get the submenu , android automatically selects first submenu in the list i.e. index =0 and immediately fires the above code and it doesn't wait for rest of the submenu to load and allow the user to select from the submens item that i have created dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in your OnOptionsItemSelected

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

     if( (item.getItemId() & NEW_MENU_ITEM ) == NEW_MENU_ITEM)  // check if its a sub menu ID
     {

       switch(item.getItemId() - NEW_MENU_ITEM)
       {
          case 0: // first sub menu option
          {
             DoSubMenu1();
             break;
          }

          case 1:: // second sub menu option
          {
             DoSubMenu2();
             break;
          }

          // and so on ..................
        }

        return;
     }
}
```